# Is there any type inference for method decorator in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, decorator

Since there is TypedPropertyDescriptor which can be used to define method decorators, is there any way to let the compiler to infer parameter types of decorated methods?

```
function test(
    target: any,
    propName: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(x: number) => any>
) {
}

class T {
  @test
  log(n) {  // <-- compiler complains that n has type of implicit any

  }
}
```

As `(x: number) => any` was passed into `TypedPropertyDescriptor`, it implies that all methods decorated by `test` should be of type `(x: number) => any`, thus above code should type check.

So TypeScript doesn't support this kind of inference yet, or do I miss something which could make this code type check?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/SierraSoftworks/Iridium/blob/release/lib/Decorators.ts

Answer (score 4):

There are many cases where TypeScript undertakes [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html), but this isn't one.

Add the type annotation to the parameter:

```
class T {
  @test
  log(n: number) {

  }
}
```

The type is still checked in relation to the decorator, even though the decorator does not provide contextual type information:

```
class T {
  @test
  log(n: string) { // ERROR!

  }
}
```